# Uneven grid when plotting date in plt

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot variable by date, days and month. Grid is uneven when month is changing. How to force size of grid in this case?

Data is loaded via Pandas, as DataFrame.
ga =

```
Reference   Organic_search  Direct  Date
0   0   0   0   2021-11-22
1   0   0   0   2021-11-23
2   0   0   0   2021-11-24
3   0   0   0   2021-11-25
4   0   0   0   2021-11-26
5   0   0   0   2021-11-27
6   0   0   0   2021-11-28
7   42  19  35  2021-11-29
8   69  33  48  2021-11-30
9   107 32  35  2021-12-01
10  62  30  26  2021-12-02
11  20  26  30  2021-12-03
12  22  22  20  2021-12-04
13  40  41  20  2021-12-05
14  14  39  26  2021-12-06
15  18  25  34  2021-12-07
16  8   21  13  2021-12-08
17  11  21  17  2021-12-09
18  23  27  20  2021-12-10
19  46  26  17  2021-12-11
20  29  42  20  2021-12-12
21  122 37  19  2021-12-13
22  97  25  29  2021-12-14
23  288 51  39  2021-12-15
24  96  29  26  2021-12-16
25  51  25  36  2021-12-17
26  23  16  21  2021-12-18
27  47  32  10  2021-12-19
```

code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,5))
ax.plot(ga.date, ga.reference)
ax.set(xlabel = 'Data', 
       ylabel = 'Ruch na stronie')

date_form = DateFormatter('%d/%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Cnr.png)

Comment: **1)** How did you load the data? Did you use Pandas? **2)** How can you get the 17/12 data shown on the graph? Do you have more data than the one shown above? **3)** Use ```ax.grid(True)```

Comment: 1) Via Pandas
2) I've just added whole DataFrame above
3) ax.grid(True) don't work here. I see the grid, the only problem I have is shape between 11-29 and 12-01 - You can see it on graph above. I want to every rectangle have same x length.

Comment: Do you not use the fomatter and use this instead to improve it? `fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=45)` What is the current version you are using?

Comment: @yaqb I wrote an answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the added data, I realized why the interval was not constant.
This is because the number of days corresponding to each month is different.
So I just made the date data into one string data. And the grid spacing was forced to be the same.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', index_col=0)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
ax.plot(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%d/%y'), df.Refference)
ax.set(xlabel='Data',
       ylabel='Ruch na stronie')
ax.grid(True)

# set xaxis interval
interval = 3
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(interval))
```

[image]